# In firestore, does using .get() with the nodejs admin sdk on a collection reference read all data into memory?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I am using the Admin SDK for Node.js, working with firestore.

I am trying to handle many documents, and therefore wonders how the following function behaves.

```
export async function test() {
    const collection = firestore.afs.collection(<some-path>);
    const items = await collection.get();
    // This method takes rather long time on a big collection. 
}
test();
```

Does the get() method reads all method up in memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading all documents in a collection into a variable, as your code does, loads them all in memory. There really isn't anywhere else to put them.

If you don't want to load all document at once, you'll want to use queries to determine what specific documents to load.

Comment: Ok - I am only working with this code to create backup. Looking forward to seeing some backup functionality from Google :)